# Why does apple use odd numbers for font size and paddings?

Tags: gui-design, ios, apple

I have learnt the use of even numbers for font sizes, spacings. The 8 point rule. But still not being able to figure out why Apple still uses odd number for font sizes, spacings and paddings.

Comment: it's device dependant. Not all devices have the same font size, sometimes is odd, sometimes is even. See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography

Answer (score 1):

Using even numbers and an 8px grid provides *one* easy way to help designers create harmonious spacing. They are not strictly necessary—just a helpful tool. There's nothing magic about even numbers and 8px units, and it's okay to not use them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about why Apple use ODD numbers though.

Comment: @JonW They use a combination of even and odd numbers, so one can conclude their font sizes are based on what works/looks best regardless of whether the number is odd or even. See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography#Specifications

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact, [humans love odd numbers](https://uxdesign.cc/odd-vs-even-number-psychology-6307047bf5de) (<-- UX Collective article). Think about it, 7 wonders of the world, trinity in everything we can define. I've always found this to be a fun detail about humans.

I couldn't find the original article that taught me this (probably, QuickSprout's Complete Guide on the Psychology of a Consumer), but I can't dig that up right now. UX Collective's article will do, the results are the same.

[UX Collective article on what types of numbers we like](https://uxdesign.cc/odd-vs-even-number-psychology-6307047bf5de)